# Detected out-of-order KTable update when updating same GlobalKtable from different input topics

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have 2.4.1 streams app which tracks 2 different topics lets say topic A and B, joins them with one GlobalKtable and sends messages to the source topic of this GlobalKtable. So like output of the app will be one of the input sources.
The problem I am experiencing is with 2 close messages (< 200 mls) in topics A and B, the output of the app from first message in topic A is not considered when next message from topic B is processed. So GlobalKtable state is rewritten with incorrect results produced by second B join with table.  And next warn is shown in the logs

> | WARN  | org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KTableSource |
> Detected out-of-order KTable update for store at
> offset 3, partition 5.  |  |

The questions are next:

1. Am I understanding correctly from https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-353%3A+Improve+Kafka+Streams+Timestamp+Synchronization that Kafka streams buffer some messages for processing and don't consider any updates done by these messages to app-state
2. To make the logic behave correctly I need to break app for two for each topic, is there any chance there will be same problem?
3. Can kafka-streams be improved to correctly process such situations, like make iteration not every n buffered messages/ n time, but every input message?

**UPDATE**

I tried to use 2 different streams aps (point 2):

1. topic A + join table -> source topic of table.
2. topic B + join table -> source topic of table.

Now see different behavior, but result is same, even with `max.task.idle.ms=1000`

`Topic A: timestamp 1626946183424`

`Topic B: timestamp 1626946183427`

Output - source table topic:

`Table topic: 0 1   timestamp 1626946183427`

`Table topic: 0 2   timestamp 1626946183424`

Out of order message too.

> Detected out-of-order KTable update for store at offset 2, partition 0

> Detected out-of-order KTable update for store at offset 2, partition 0